# Why does an exiting child process cause the parent's sigsuspend call to return on macOS?

Tags: c, unix, fork, posix

Consider the following C code for a POSIX system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CONTINUE_SIGNAL SIGINT

void continue_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    printf("[P] Continuing process with pid = %d...\n", getpid());
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    sigset_t mask;
    pid_t pid;

    // Block the CONTINUE_SIGNAL for now.
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, CONTINUE_SIGNAL);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)  {
        printf("[C] This is the child (pid %d).\n", getpid());
        return 0;
    }

    printf("[P] Parent (pid %d) has spawned child (pid %d).\n", getpid(), pid);

    // Call the 'continue_handler' when CONTINUE_SIGNAL is received.
    act.sa_sigaction = continue_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(CONTINUE_SIGNAL, &act, NULL);
    printf("[P] Waiting for CONTINUE_SIGNAL...\n");

    // Block all signals except CONTINUE_SIGNAL and wait for it to occur.
    sigfillset(&mask);
    sigdelset(&mask, CONTINUE_SIGNAL);
    sigsuspend(&mask);
    printf("[P] Signal received. Exiting...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have removed all error checking to be able to represent it in a more compact form. However, I have verified that all the functions return successfully in both of the following cases.

On a Linux system, the code does exactly what I expect it to do: The parent process spawns a child process and waits for `SIGINT` before it continues to execute `continue_handler`.

```
[P] Parent (pid 804) has spawned child (pid 805).
[P] Waiting for CONTINUE_SIGNAL...
[C] This is the child (pid 805).
  <press Ctrl+C>
[P] Continuing process with pid = 804...
[P] Signal received. Exiting...
```

On macOS, however, I obtain the following output (without any interaction):

```
[P] Parent (pid 6024) has spawned child (pid 6025).
[P] Waiting for CONTINUE_SIGNAL...
[C] This is the child (pid 6025).
[P] Signal received. Exiting...
```

Obviously, the `sigsuspend` call of the parent process (pid 6024) returns immediately after the child process exits. Although `SIGINT` does not seem to be triggered, `sigsuspend` returns an `errno` of `EINTR`, i.e., reports a successful termination by one of the non-masked signals. Note that if I prevent the child process from exiting, `sigsuspend` does *not* return by itself and instead waits for `SIGINT` to be delivered.

Is there an issue with the way I am using the API? Or is there maybe a certain degree of flexibility in the POSIX specification that makes both of these behaviors expected?

Comment: Two things for you to try: (1) Use a completely full mask (all signals blocked) in the initial call to sigprocmask. (2) Install a handler for SIGCHLD as well as SIGINT. Does that handler get called?

Comment: @zwol I've tried it out: (1) Blocking all signals in the initial `sigprocmask` call does not change the behavior. (2) Installing a handler to `SIGCHLD` while keeping `CONTINUE_SIGNAL` constant does not change the behavior either, i.e., does not result in a call of the new handler. And although you didn't ask for it explicitly: (3) Setting `CONTINUE_SIGNAL` to `SIGCHLD` instead of adding a second handler causes the original handler to be called.

Comment: You can not safely call `printf()` from within a signal handler.  In strictly-conforming C, it's not safe to call any library function. Per [footnote 188 of the C 11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  [POSIX allows for the calling of async-signal-safe functions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) and only async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That's not a concern for this program because the signal is delivered only when primary control flow is blocked in sigsuspend.

Comment: @bosonic I'm afraid I'm stumped. It almost smells like a bug in OSX's implementation of sigsuspend. Can you test your program on one of the fully open source BSDs? If you can reproduce the same behavior there, it'll be easier to fig into.

Comment: This can be demonstrated without the sigaction complication.  Set an alarm for five seconds.  Fork a child that sleeps for a second or two before terminating.  Have the parent `sigsuspend` allowing SIGALRM only.  On OS X the parent's `sigsuspend` will be EINTRrupted and execution resumes; whereas on Linux, the parent is terminated by an alarm clock.

Comment: there are several functions that are 'unsafe' to use in a signal handler.  The function: `printf()` is one of functions to NOT use.  Suggest using: `write( 1, .... );`

Comment: Normally, the parent process waits for the child process to exit via either `wait()` or `waitpid()`  which only takes a single line of code,  so why complicate things by involving signals and all the related code?

Comment: @user3629249, signal handlers and normal reaping practices are red herrings.  The question here is, Why, on OS X, is `sigsuspend` _with SIGCHLD masked off_ interrupted by child process termination?

Comment: Is SIGCHLD maskable?

Comment: @zwol Thank you for your suggestion. I have now executed the same code on FreeBSD 12.1. On this OS, the application waits for me to issue a `SIGINT` before continuing. I'm afraid that analyzing the FreeBSD sources probably won't help to track this issue down.

Comment: @bosonic At this point I think you should report this as a bug to Apple.

Comment: @zwol I have submitted this "developer feedback," with a simpler demonstration, to Apple as FB7731811.

Answer (score 0):

Please read: [signals in MAX OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/signal.3.html)

especially the statement:

```
To ignore the signal, func should be SIG_IGN.
```

somehow, I do not see that in your code.